# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

With:

```
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT COA_BOOK_OF_CHARTACCOUNT ( :CHART) FROM DUAL").setParameter("CHART", 3000);
query.list();
```

I'm getting

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -10
```

The `COA_BOOK_OF_CHARTACCOUNT` is a function and returns a cursor.

Comment: `-10` is not a valid JDBC type (it isn't defined in `java.sql.Types`); which would indicate this could be a vendor specific type, so what are the data types involved?

Comment: It is just a single row of a table contained in a cursor.

Comment: And what are the types of the columns of that row, and what is the type of the `chart` parameter?

Comment: two NUMBER columns and a single NVARCHAR2, the type of chart is NUMBER also.